# SED command contained in nested loops

Tags: xml, regex, sed

I have a scenario wherein a file contains xml tags. There is a tag like  `<abcd .... param="paramvalue">` under which I have another tag named `<efgh="value">` under which another tag `<hijk>` is present. I need to count the no. of `<hijk>` tags present in each `<abcd>` tag and I have to display the value of param in `<abcd>` tag and value of `<efgh>` tag.

For example,

FILENAME.xml

```
<abcd...... xyz="value1">
      <efgh="value2">
          <hijk>
            ....
          </hijk>
           ....
      </efgh>
      <efgh="value3">
         ....
     </efgh>
       ....
</abcd>

<abcd...... xyz="value4">

      .......

</abcd>

    ......
```

I used

```
sed -n '/xyz=*/p' FILENAME.xml | cut -d =  -f 4 | echo "xyz:` cut -d " " -f 1`" && sed -n '/efgh=*/p' FILENAME.xml | cut -d =  -f 2 | echo "efgh:`cut -d " " -f 1`" && grep -c '`<hijk>`' FILENAME.xml
```

But I got the total count of `<hijk>` tags and got a separate list of xyz values and a separate list of efgh values.

I need the solution in this format,

```
xyz="value1"

  efgh="value2"

   no. of hijk tags

....

xyz="valueN"

   efgh="valueN"

   no. of hijk tags

....
```

and so on.

And I thought I could use 3 inner loops along with sed command to iterate. Am I correct?
Even if I am, I need help doing so.
Please help.

Comment: don't use sed for this, awk is lot more powerfull in this case (sed cannot count, ...)

Comment: can you provide an example for this instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F[\ \<\>] '/xyz=/{print $(NF-1)} ; /efgh=/{print $(NF-1)} /hijk/{count++} /\/efgh/{print "no. of hjkl tags " count; count=0}' sam1
```

will produe the output as

```
xyz="value1"
efgh="value2"
no. of hjkl tags 2
efgh="value3"
no. of hjkl tags 0
xyz="value4"
```

`-F[\ \<\>]` will set field seperator as `<` or `>` or (space)

`/xyz=/{print $(NF-1)}` selects line with `xyz` and prints the `param="paramvalue"`

`/hijk/{count++}` increaments a counter, `count` when `hijk` tag occures

`/\/efgh/{print "no. of hjkl tags " count; count=0}` prints and reset counter, `count` once the end tag `<\efgh>` occures.

Comment: wt does this indicate $(NF-1)??

Comment: `NF` is numbero fields or columns, $(NF-1) would be the second last column mathing `param="value"`